# AngularJS $http params

Tags: angularjs

I am using the following function in my AngularJS app, but I am facing a problem in the api call as it returns the following error:

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected token {
at Object.parse (native)
at fromJson (http://localhost/app/lib/angular/angular.js:1036:14)
at $HttpProvider.defaults.defaults.transformResponse (http://localhost/app/lib/angular/angular.js:6937:18)
at http://localhost/app/lib/angular/angular.js:6912:12
at Array.forEach (native)
at forEach (http://localhost/app/lib/angular/angular.js:303:11)
at transformData (http://localhost/app/lib/angular/angular.js:6911:3)
at transformResponse (http://localhost/app/lib/angular/angular.js:7576:17)
at wrappedCallback (http://localhost/app/lib/angular/angular.js:10930:81)
at http://localhost/app/lib/angular/angular.js:11016:26
```

After researching I found that the problem is in params, but I am not sure what is wrong in it...can someone please help me by telling me what I am doing wrong here and how to fix it?

```
 saveContact: function(contact){
       var deferred = $q.defer();       
        var params = {
              name: contact.name,
              phone: contact.phone
        }



       $http({ method:'GET',
               url:'http://localhost/contacts.php?action=newcontact',
               params: params
             }).success(function(data,status,headers,config){
                 deferred.resolve(data);
             }).error(function(data,status,headers,config){
                 deferred.reject(status);
             });
       return deferred.promise;   
   }
```

Comment: Just out of curiousity, why does it matter?

Comment: Correct, I think the problem is beyond this, updating the question

Comment: @Sprottenwels I've deeply researched the problem and found it is not about sequence rather it is about the params itself as you can see from the error, but I am not sure what is wrong with it!

Comment: What are the values of contact.name and contact.phone?

Comment: @cliff.meyers Here is the result of console.log(params); Object {name: "john", phone: "123456"…}
name: "john"
phone: "123456"

Answer (score 0):

I would guess the problem is that you already have query params in your url ("?action=newcontact").  angular is probably trying to add the params contact.name and contact.phone as additional query params with another question mark.

I would try this:

```
  var params = {
              action: 'newcontact',
              name: contact.name,
              phone: contact.phone
        }
```

And change the GET url to just

```
http://localhost/contacts.php
```

Alternatively, is it possible that you are supposed to POST the new contact?

Comment: Just tried it but I still get the same exact error :( Unfortunately I must use GET :(

Comment: Actually looking at the error it doesn't like what's coming back.  Are you sure the service is returning valid JSON?

Comment: Here is the result of console.log(params); Object {name: "john", phone: "123456"…} name: "john" phone: "123456"  I tried many things to make it work but it always return the same error :( what is worse is that I am not sure what is wrong here :(

Comment: What is the HTTP response in the browser debugger?

Comment: I don't really think that there is a problem on server, as the server always returning 200 OK. One thing I noticed also. This api has many params beside name and phone, one of them is integer, so the table saving all strings save data successfully, while that with integer field don't save data sent to it....so this make me doubt that it might be complaining about trying to save string as integer...but then I am not sure how to make specific fields sent as integers? Any thoughts?

Comment: The HTTP status of the response is 200.  However, the response also contains data that should look like JSON, but probably isn't.

Comment: meaning? sorry i didn't get it

Comment: the GET method is returning data in addition to the response code.  You can see this data by using the browser debugging tools (Firebug or Chrome developer tools).  angular expects this data to be in JSON format, but it's either empty or in some other format.  Again, usually when you create a new record, you use a POST request, so I'm not convinced you understand the API

Comment: I fully understand the difference between Post and GET, and yes normally you would use POST due to many cons in sending data using Get, but it is not a taboo to use GET, at least for testing or whatever. Anyway, back to the returned JSON format, what format does http expects?

Comment: The $http will interpret the response based on the Content-Type header in the response.  Presumably you have an Content-Type of application/json but the content is not valid JSON.  An empty response is not valid JSON, for example.  I would check the API on the web service to see what you should expect in the response to your GET